# Server for Best Performance with Zend

Tags: performance, hadoop, cluster-computing, zend-server

I'm developing a big application with Zend Framework, and I started asking myself which is the best server for it.

I know there is Zend Cluster Server, but a lot of companies use Apache Hadoop. What is the difference? Which is the better choose for a zend developer?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you cannot compare Zend Cluster Server with Apache Hadoop. You should first understand what each of these do/deliver.

Maybe you should focus on Zend Cluster Server (Zend Server, etc) for your Zend Framework application. If you do need distributed computations (e.g mapreduce) or a distributed filesystem on a-large-scale then you could consider Apache Hadoop and it's subprojects.